# Return to Main, but with free format

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I'm writing a Virtual Time Machine
I want to go back to the beginning when a year is evaluated, but with free format I can't just say "GO TO MAIN"
I basically want the program say: do you want to evaluate other years?"
IF yes GO TO "MAIN" (that there isn't, because for writing long text I use free format)
IF NO stop run.

```
ACCEPT INPUT1
           IF INPUT1 = 1900
                  DISPLAY"London reaches 4,300,000 inhabitants"
                  DISPLAY"Paris reaches 2,000,000 inhabitants"
                  DISPLAY"From 14 May to 28 October, the 2nd Olympics will take place in Paris."
                  DISPLAY"In Great Britain, on 28 February, the Labour representation committee was founded, under the leadership of Ramsay McDonald (1866-1937), which united, within the new party, associations and unions of socialist orientation."
                  DISPLAY"Bernhard von Bülow succeeded the Prince of Hohenlohe, Chlodwig, as the new Chancellor of the German Reich (1900 - 1909)."
                  DISPLAY"The American Schools of Oriental Research is founded."
               END-IF
               DISPLAY "Do you want to analyze the events of other years??"
               ACCEPT Q
               IF Q = "Y" OR "YES" OR "y" OR "yes" OR "Yes" GO TO 
                   ELSE DISPLAY "OK, GOOD JOB :)"
                       DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 3 SECONDS..."
                       CALL "CBL_OC_NANOSLEEP" USING "1000000000"
                   END-CALL
                   DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 2 SECONDS.."
                   CALL "CBL_OC_NANOSLEEP" USING "1000000000"
                   END-CALL
                   DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 1 SECOND."
                   CALL "CBL_OC_NANOSLEEP" USING "300000000"
                   END-CALL
               STOP RUN.
```

Have you any ideas? Thanks a lot:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Free-form reference-format did not drop paragraphs or `GO TO`, therefore you could simply add those and are fine.
But I'd suggest to have a main logic including the loop as a loop and structure the code a bit, in this case:

```
  MAIN SECTION.
     PERFORM TIME-MACHINE UNTIL NOT (Q = "Y" OR "YES")
     PERFORM ENDING-CINEMA
     GOBACK.
  *>
  TIME-MACHINE SECTION.
     ACCEPT INPUT1
     IF INPUT1 = 1900
        DISPLAY"London reaches 4,300,000 inhabitants"
        DISPLAY"Paris reaches 2,000,000 inhabitants"
        DISPLAY"From 14 May to 28 October, the 2nd Olympics will take place in Paris."
        DISPLAY"In Great Britain, on 28 February, the Labour representation committee was founded, under the leadership of Ramsay McDonald (1866-1937), which united, within the new party, associations and unions of socialist orientation."
        DISPLAY"Bernhard von Bülow succeeded the Prince of Hohenlohe, Chlodwig, as the new Chancellor of the German Reich (1900 - 1909)."
        DISPLAY"The American Schools of Oriental Research is founded."
     END-IF
     DISPLAY "Do you want to analyze the events of other years??"
     ACCEPT Q
     INSPECT Q (1:3) CONVERTING "yes" to "YES"
     CONTINUE.
  *>
  ENDING-CINEMA SECTION.
     DISPLAY "OK, GOOD JOB :)"
     DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 3 SECONDS..."
     CONTINUE AFTER 1 SECOND  *> for "old" GnuCOBOL use a call to "C$SLEEP" USING "1"
     DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 2 SECONDS.."
     CONTINUE AFTER 1 SECOND
     DISPLAY "I EXIT IN 1 SECOND."
     CONTINUE AFTER 1 SECOND
     CONTINUE.
```

Comment: ok, it works, but it says it needs the "end-perform"
But for everything else it works

Comment: The final CONTINUE statements in TIME-MACHINE SECTION and ENDING-CINEMA SECTION are unnecessary.

Comment: @ScottNelson yes, the `CONTINUE`part of `CONTINUE.` is not necessary but a "style" issue, as all the sections are (one could either inline everything or use `GO TO`)